# Matplotlib.pyplot: force exponential axis label notation

Tags: python, matplotlib

In a plot created by matplotlib.pyplot, how can I force the axis labels to be shown in exponential notation? This seems to be done automatically for values < 1e-6, but for, say, 5e-6 I get "0.000005". I'd prefer to have it shown as "5e-6" also for this range.

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FormatStrFormatter    `"%e"` is exponential

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It *seems* like you should be able to set the power limits of the [`ScalarFormatter`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter) for the axes. (untested code)

```
# Set limits to x < 10^1 and x > 10^-1 
# (overlapping, thus all inclusive, hopefully)
gca().get_yaxis().get_major_formatter().set_powerlimits((0, 0))
```

Comment: You can do one better and just call `set_powerlimits` on `gca().get_major_formatter()`

Comment: @voithos: I had to use `gca().yaxis.get_major_formatter().set_powerlimits((-1,1))`. Is there an (elegant) way to apply the change to both axes in one go?

@tcaswell: How do you do this? Calling `set_powerlimits` without arguments gived an error.

Comment: @gandi2223 Sorry, dropped a layer.  The elegant way is to just do it do both.  If you want to change the default, set `axes.formatter.limits` in `matplotlib.rc`